# How can I make private static field of the static class thread safe?

Tags: c#, static, thread-safety

I have a static class which has a private Dictionary. I have written public methods to add and remove objects to it. Now I want to ensure that when I remove one of the items from dictionary, noone else is using it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you want to ensure that no-one else is using the *dictionary*, or no-one else is using the value which was *in* the dictionary?

You can solve the first using locking... but you can't really do the second. Someone could fetch a reference to the object from the dictionary and store that reference for as long as they like. There *may* be a solution if the value is an interface type - you could delegate all calls through an extra "wrapper" class, and invalidate that wrapper class. I can go into more details if you want, but I'm *hoping* you're really just interested in the first type of safety :)

That can be achieved like this:

```
private static readonly object mutex = new object();

// Or whatever
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> map =
    new Dictionary<string, string>();

public static void AddEntry(string key, string value)
{
    lock (mutex)
    {
        map[key] = value;
    }
}

public static string GetValue(string key, string value)
{
    lock (mutex)
    {
        return map[key];
    }
}
```

Obviously you'll want to tweak how you're using the dictionary.

If you're using .NET 4, another alternative would be to use [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) which is already thread-safe.

Comment: @Jon: got a question. I usually use the dictionary itself as a sync root (when it's a private field) instead of creating a separate object. What's the advantage of using a separate object in this case?

Comment: @Jon: Thanks for your reply. I wanted to achieve the second thing you mentioned. i.e. ensure noone else is using a value when I'm trying to remove it from dictionary. My application is not using .NET 4.0. It's on .NET 3.5. However, could you please provide more details to achieve it? (You have already mentioned wrapper class).

Comment: @jgauffin: I don't know whether code within `Dictionary` syncs on itself. As a matter of principle, I almost always lock on an object which is *only* used for locking within my class. That means I never need to worry that *other* code will be using that object for locking too.

Comment: @CSharpLearner: Well it's going to depend heavily on what kind of object you're talking about, and what sort of use you're trying to prohibit. You won't be able to stop client code from maintaining whatever reference you return... but you *may* be able to make that reference effectively useless. More details please.

Comment: @Jon: The static dictionary is 'Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>'. This dictionary is kind of cache where other parts of program do a lookup. Lets say, if some other thread is iterating through the inner dictionary and at the same time I try to remove it from outer dictionary, it'll cause problems. So I want to prohibit this removal of inner dictionary if some other thread is using it.

Comment: @CSharpLearner: That's tricky to say the least - and you could easily end up blocking the removal thread for a long time. What problem would be caused if the iterating thread *did* keep iterating when the dictionary was removed? I would try to redesign to avoid this problem - it's going to be awkward to solve in its current form.

Comment: @Jon: Will iterating thread not get any exception when I'm removing the thing which it's iterating?.. Or vice versa i.e. removal operation won't get a problem if I'm removing the thing already in use? From your last comment, I think I need to get it cleared first. Thanks for your guidance so far :)

Comment: @Jon: If a dictionary is private, what other code can lock on it? Also, why does it matter if the dictionary locks itself using `this`. It's still synchronized thanks to your lock so it should not matter.

Comment: @jgauffin - I guess it could cause issues if the dictionary was locking and denying recursive lock acquires - you might get an exception. However, I too use the approach you describe and have never had any problems.

Comment: Thank you all. I understand that in its present form, only locking on the dictionary is possible. To achieve lock on members of the dictionary, I need to look for some other design.

Comment: @JonSkeet, if mutes was an instance variable, what would happen then? Would it be working as well?

Comment: @Alexandre: If it were an instance variable, you couldn't use it from a static method...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using [lock Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)